# Determining whether html5 geolocation function is available AND whether it knows where you are?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I'm experimenting with HTML5 geolocation, and embedded a small test script into a page to return my present co-ordinates.

The current application I have in mind for using this is as a 'nice to have' feature on site i'm working on - it includes a 'find my nearest' lookup on some locations, and I figured that if you had a location aware device, I could easily include 'to my current location' alongside the normal 'to my postal/zip code'.  I'm not interested in loading a bunch of extra libraries and fallbacks for such a small and non-essential feature.  If you have a capable device, great, if not, you won't ever see the option.

So I tried the script on an iPad, and as expected - I was prompted for permission to use my present location, to which I agreed, and my test script returned my present location.  Total win.

I tried the same on my desktop, since i'm using Firefox 4 and its a HTML5 compliant browser.  It asked me if I wanted to share my location, and then promptly returned the error that it didn't know my location (because its a desktop computer and has no GPS).  I thought this rendered the original question of 'do you want to share your location' somewhat pointless - it could needlessly annoy people who might have thought they could use a feature that they in fact can't.

So, what is a reliable technique to detect if:

> a) The browser can access HTML5 geolocation
>
> **AND**
>
> b) The browser knows or can find out what the users location is.

Without actually calling the geolocation function beforehand, and asking the user an annoying, and unnecessary question?

For a) i'm simply using:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCoords,handleGeoErrors);    
}
```

But for b) the only answer I have involves having called getCurrentPosition, which triggers the question to the user.

Any thoughts on this, anyone?

Comment: This sounds more like a bug in Firefox, which you could report using [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/). If there is no geolocation information to provide, then Firefox shouldn't be asking if it has permission to provide it; it should just throw an error.

Comment: I can see how it might be a bug, but at the same time, I can see how it might not be.  The website only knows that the feature is available to the browser being used, it doesn't know whether the browser has the actual information until it asks, but then its too late.  I can get the site to say that location information is unavailable - but only after asking for it.  It would be better if it could just say 'if I wanted location information, do you have it?' before then bothering the user with the question as to whether it should be provided or not.

Comment: And interestingly, IE9 DOES provide a location on the desktop computer (albeit inaccurate by 140 miles!).  Opera, Safari and Chrome, along with Firefox all ask the question, but cannot provide the location.

Comment: Desktop Firefox should still be able to provide a location based on your IP - what do you have in your `geo.wifi.uri` setting in `about:config`?

Comment: Unchanged from default - which reads https://www.google.com/loc/json

Comment: The link returns a JSON parsing error, so it looks like something in the default settings for the browser, or in google's service is borked.

Comment: The error is because you're not sending it any JSON to parse - [the format for the request is described here](http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI) (scroll down to Request Format)

Comment: So i'm assuming that is because my desktop computer doesn't have GPS, and doesn't use Wifi?  But how is it failing on just using my IP address if thats what is intended (it appears IE9 is doing that, although it looks like my IP is showing up pretty far away from where I actually am).  For me to change the default config of my browser would defeat the object, as it would still fail for everyday users who hadn't done that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not going to be a way to do this because the way a browser finds out whether or not it can get geolocation information (in the absence of a direct connection to a GPS device) is to send a request to the configured geolocation service and see what it says.  Unfortunately at that point it's already shared the personal information that the annoying question is supposed to prevent being shared without permission.

Comment: You would think it would have been able to send a 'pre' request just saying "do you even have this data?" and get back a yes/no answer - so we wouldn't have to bother the user unless it was present... That way I could hide the 'current location' link altogether, but oh well!

Comment: @Codecraft But how will it determine whether or not it has data for your IP address/wireless access point signatures unless you send it your IP address/wireless access point signatures?

Comment: Your browser/device knowing where you are using GPS or other data is nothing to do with the request to share it from the site - the site is just asking to be given data.  Surely the browser/device could know in advance whether it had any data to give even before the user went to my, or any website?

Comment: @Codecraft You always have your IP address to give, it's implicit in the request

Comment: Agreed, in which case we shouldn't be returning an error - we should always get some sort of location information.

Comment: @Codecraft Yep, unless there's a bug of some kind as Brian suggested